# From where to download fashion-gen dataset

Tags: database, dataset

Can anybody tell me from where i can download fashion-gen dataset used in Fashion-Gen: The Generative Fashion Dataset and Challenge. i filled the form but didn't get mail.

I want to use this dataset for my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

this is maybe late for you... but for others, I share.

I found train and validation data and upload them in my google drive.
You can find the link here:
https://github.com/monib110/fashionstyle-generation-GMM/blob/main/README.md

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).